# How can I alter colors on Theme.Holo.Dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-xml, android-dialog

I got an activity showing as a dialog using

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
```

in the manifest file

How can I change the colors of the text and background in the dialog/activity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to use [this](https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs) library for custom dialogs. But of course you can build your custom dialog yourself. You can't change the color only (for example the line) without making a custom dialog with your own resources.

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/dialog_title_holo.xml/?v=source) is the source for the original holo dialog. You can reproduce this, but using the library is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You have to just define your own custom style in values/styles.xml to achieve it.

Step 1- put below code in values/styles.xml file

```
   <style name="UserDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
   <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
   <item name="android:background">#c39797</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#E64C66</item>
   </style>
```

Step-2 And use it AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@style/UserDialog"
```

Note: you need to create a transparent png drawable if you want to add